# Pass property from controller to Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model, controller, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a variable from a method in my Controller to a method in a Model. Since the method in the Model takes one argument (which was designed earlier), I cannot pass my variable as an argument to the method in the Model. And also, the method in this Model is called by other controllers too, so if I change the argument, I have to change all the controllers too, which would be a tedious task.
What I have been trying so far is- I created one MyVariableClass and declared a property. Then I instantiated that class and set the property string to the variable that I wanted to pass. Now, in my Model's method, I instantiated the same MyVariableClass again, but when I did that, the value of the variable was set to null. The code I have right now is -

```
 public ActionResult ItemInformation( string id)
     {
        //Pass a string to MyVariable
        MyVariableVClass params = new MyVariableClass();
        params.myVariable = "abc";

   //This is what My Model is taking as an argument(id), and I don't want to 
   //pass mYvariable along with that argument because it will break other controllers
  // too which calls this method
    var itemInformation = _repository.GetItemInformation(id);
   return View(itemInformation);
    }
```

and MyVariableClass

```
  public  class MyVariableClass
  {
     public string myVariable { get; set; }
  }
```

and the method in My Model

```
  public IList<Items> GetItemInformation(string itemId)
    {

      MyVariableClass webType = new MyVariableClass();
      var _params = webType.myVariable;
       //Check this variable and perform database query 
      if (_params =="this") 
       {
        var query = myFirstQuery;
       }
      else
       {
       var query = mySecondQuery;
       }
     //return ....
   }
```

Anybody has solution to this? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You don't appear to be passing your instance of `MyVariableClass` (i.e. `params`) to anything.  Instead, you create it twice, once in your controller and once in your model.  How is that supposed to accomplish anything?   (also, your models really shouldn't have behavior -- methods -- they are intended to hold data, not be repositories for random bits of code.  Put that `GetItemInformation` behavior somewhere else.  It has no business being in a model.)

Comment: Yeah! Actually my question was how do I pass the instance of MyVariableClass to getItemInformation without changing the current aruguments of GetItemInformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why subclassing your model and overriding the `GetItemInformation` method wouldn't work? Or, even easier, why not just overload the `GetItemInformation` method with one that takes two strings? Your other controllers can still use the one that only takes a single string.

```
  public IList<Items> GetItemInformation(string itemId, MyVariableClass webType)
    {

      var _params = webType.myVariable;
       //Check this variable and perform database query 
      if (_params == "this") 
       {
        var query = myFirstQuery;
       }
      else
       {
       var query = mySecondQuery;
       }
     //return ....
   }

  public IList<Items> GetItemInformation(string itemId)
  {
     MyVariableClass fauxType = new MyVariableClass();
     fauxType.myVariable = "not this";

     return GetItemInformation(itemId, fauxType);
  }
```

Comment: The only reason I am not using overloading is to avoid duplicate code on two methods. I just need to have the variable value so that I can check condition and write my LINQ. So, if I overload GetItemInformation, for a single line of code, i have to repeat my whole method.

Comment: @ACS please see the code I've added. You really don't need to repeat your whole method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [session variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx).